# Changing scale point in CSS

Tags: css

`.bunch` is an image. Is there a way to change this animation so that it scales from the bottom of the image so its appears from the floor instead? At the moment it scales from the middle.

```
.bunch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left:320px;
  -webkit-animation: flowerGrow 3s forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes flowerGrow {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0)}
  100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1)}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

See [`transform-origin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin):

```
.bunch {
  position: absolute;
  top: 250px;
  left:320px;
  -webkit-animation: flowerGrow 3s forwards;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flowerGrow {
  0% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(0)}
  100% { -webkit-transform: scaleY(1)}
}
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gNSNG/)</kbd>